# Selenium Doesn't Open My Local Browser Even I Specify It

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Chrome browser with selenium. The browser has profiles. It's running fine when I give correct binary path but if I don't pass the correct path it doesn't run.

The problem is when it runs, it does not pick up the profile. I don't see them along with settings or the extensions. It's a completely new instance of the browser. What can be the case?

Here is my code:

```
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function createNewChromeProfile() {
    const options = new Options();

    options.setChromeBinaryPath('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome');
    options.addArguments(`--user-data-dir=/Users/bfzli/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`);

    const driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    return driver;
}

async function main() {
    const driver = await createNewChromeProfile();
    await driver.get('https://google.com');
}

main();
```

I tried to remove the binary path, it didn't work.

Comment: you have to call `driver.get()` method with desired URL as the argument to open your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `--user-data-dir` option to your Chrome profile that you gonna open, so you got empty profile.

```js
options.setChromeBinaryPath('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome');
    
options.addArguments(`--user-data-dir=path-to-chrome/chrome-profile`);
```

on MacOS by default it is

```
 /Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<PROFILE_NAME>
```

Also you can try to create custom profile for your automation and define it's pass, or clone Default profile in project directory and use it

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

// ...

const options = new Options();

options.setChromeBinaryPath('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome');
    
const customProfileDir = path.join(__dirname, 'custom-profile');
options.addArguments(`--user-data-dir=${customProfileDir}`);

const defaultProfileDir = '/Users/bfzli/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default';
await fs.copy(defaultProfileDir, customProfileDir);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but still is not working, now I have also updated the question with the user data dir, but still is not opening the default profile, in case i don't pas a profile, it still needs to open my default one.

Comment: @bfzli I think, there can be issue with `Default` profile itself. Maybe you should create custom profile for automation and define it's path or clone existing one.

Comment: I think that Selenium doesn't allow you by default to use your chrome profiles, you need to create new ones for that chrome driver, I'm trying to use it my default installed browser, where I have all the profiles.

Comment: @bfzli try to copy Default to custom dir, maybe it would help

Comment: I don't want selenium to start its own env, this is my issue.